# How to write data in multiple csv files in a time loop

Tags: python, csv

Here is my problem. Thanks to a python program I create a csv file which is filled with measurement data. But in fact, my measurement campaign will last 6 months. So to permit me to study the data during tests, I want to modify my program to create a new csv file per week of the test period. 
I was thinking to use a while loop but I have some troubles to write it...

Thank you for your help and I hope I was clear.

Here are my functions which permit me to create and write my actual csv file

```py
def create_csv(measurement_name_file, fielnames):
    with open('{}.csv'.format(measurement_name_file), 'a') as measurement_file:
        measurement_writer = csv.writer(measurement_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        measurement_writer.writerow(fieldnames)


def write_csv(measurement_name_file, data):
    with open('{}.csv'.format(measurement_name_file), 'a') as measurement_file:
        measurement_writer = csv.writer(measurement_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        measurement_writer.writerow(data)
```

And here I add my data in my csv file. All the data (relative_humidity and temperature) are read at a timestamp.

```py
measurement_name_file = 'Measurement_1wk_5mn'
    fieldnames = ['timestamp', 'temperature_1', 'relative_humidty_1', 'temperature_2',
                  'relative_humidty_2', 'temperature_3', 'relative_humidty_3', 'temperature_4',
                  'relative_humidty_4']

create_csv(measurement_name_file, fieldnames)

write_csv(measurement_name_file, [timestamp, temperature1, relative_humidty1, temperature2, relative_humidty2,
                                                     temperature3, relative_humidty3, temperature4, relative_humidty4])
```

Comment: Can you specify what the exact problem with the loop is? We can't see the loop in your code so it is hard to help you with it.

Comment: you could use week number in filename base on timestamp. But I don't understand why you need loop for this.

Comment: I don't know why you use `create_csv` if you can do the same using `write_csv` - `write_csv(measurement_name_file, fieldnames)`

Comment: I cannot follow your motivation. Even if you write your file for 6 months before closing it, you can read and copy it while it is being written.

Comment: you can use `week_number = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).isocalendar()[1]` to get week number based on timestamp and write data to second file (at the same time) with week_number in filename. This way you can have all data in main file and weekly data in other files.

Comment: The loop is not written yet. I'm working on it but it's hard because i'm e beginner with python. The loop will permit me to create a new csv file each week.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes I agree but my co-worker on this project think that would be easier to analyse.

Comment: The script will only do something (write) once a week? If that's the case, it might be better to just schedule it e.g. with crontab to only run once a week. If, on the other hand, the script will be running all the time (e.g. collecting the data), then the suggestion by @furas should help.

Comment: @sg.sysel yes the script will not be interrupt during the measurement campaign. I'm trying to use furas' suggestion. Thank you guys